# How to convert 150+ categorical variables efficiently for feature importance using XGB?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, xgboost, feature-selection

I am trying to plot a feature importance plot that provides me with intuitive column names when it comes to their interpretation. Currently, I have a dataset mixed of numerical and 150+ categorical variables. None, of these categorical variables are ordinal. I attempted using get_dummies but I am worried about the dummy trap, speed due to too many resulting columns. How can I make this more efficient and accurate?

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

#create dummies for all object features only and leave numerical column as is - ISSUE: RUNS FOR TOO LONG AND EVENTUALLY BREAKS!
X_encoded=pd.get_dummies(data=df, columns=df(['object']).columns)

# Define model
    model = XGBClassifier()
    pipeline = Pipeline([
        ("preprocessing", preprocessing_pipeline),
        ("classifier", model)
    ])
       

#test, train split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_encoded, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42, stratify=y_closed)

#fit
trained_pipeline = pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)

#plot feature imp

%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
N_FEATURES = 10 #top 10 only
feature_names = preprocessing_pipeline.transform(X_train.head(1)).columns
importances = model.feature_importances_
indices = np.argsort(importances)[-N_FEATURES:]

plt.figure(figsize=(15, 8))
plt.title('Feature Importances')
plt.show()
```

The issue is that the get_dummies runs for hours and eventually my kernel dies. How can this be optimized?

Comment: maybe better ask on similar portal for [DataScience](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: try `LabelEncoder` of sklearn !

Comment: @AayushShah I fear that will assume ordinality, doesn't it?